# How to use applescripts do shell script without quotes

Tags: bash, applescript, sudo, quotes

I have a program in bash that will change my shown MAC Address. I want to make this program into an applescript using "do shell script". However, whenever I run the code in the "do shell script" function, it does not work. This is strange because it works in terminal.

This is on my Mac computer, and I believe it to be an issue with the required quotes after the "do shell script" function. I have tried changing the quotation order, but it does not seem to work.

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether "$(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//')"
```

Here is the base code

```
do shell script "sudo ifconfig en0 ether "$(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//')"" with administrator privileges
```

Here is the AppleScript variation of this code.

It was expected that this code would change my MAC Address, but instead it returned a "error -212"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what error -212 is, but in AppleScript, the (double) quote is used to delimit strings, so to use it *in* a string it needs to be escaped with a backslash, for example

```
do shell script "ifconfig en0 ether \"$(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//')\"" with administrator privileges
```

Note that `sudo` shouldn’t be used with `administrator privileges` - see Apple’s [Technical Note TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html).